# Vulkan Device Lost after submitting single-time CommandBuffer

Tags: vulkan

I have written a basic Vulkan renderer a while and it worked fine. It then broke(something with the power supply) and I reinstalled the Vulkan drivers to version 1.0.42.0 and since then it gives me the error VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST when submitting a CommandBuffer for singe-time use(loading textures etc). I have tried the code on a different device with a different GPU, and there it works just fine. The exact breaking code:

```
vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffer);

VkSubmitInfo submitInfo =
    init::SubmitInfo();
submitInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;
submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = &commandBuffer;


vkQueueSubmit(context->transferQueue, 1, &submitInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE);
//works fine until now
vkQueueWaitIdle(context->transferQueue);
//This gives me VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST
vkFreeCommandBuffers(context->device, context->cmdTempPool, 1, &commandBuffer);
//Also doesn't work since commandbuffer is still in queue
```

It also only seems to happen during initialization, since it isn't giving me any errors during runtime(actual rendering code), but they occur again during cleanup(deleting textures and buffers)
Have there been any reports or workarounds for this problem?

The exact validation layer output is:

```
ParameterValidation: vkQueueWaitIdle: returned VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST, 
indicating that the logical device has been lost
DS: Attempt to free command buffer (0x000002D18AAF1A90) which is in use. For 
more information refer to Vulkan Spec Section '5.3. Command Buffer 
Allocation and Management' which states 'All elements of pCommandBuffers 
must not be in the pending state' 
(https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-
extensions/html/vkspec.html#vkFreeCommandBuffers)
ParameterValidation: vkQueueSubmit: returned VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST, 
indicating that the logical device has been lost
```

**EDIT:**
since it seems to only happen when transitioning image layouts, here is the code for that:

```
void util::transitionImageLayout(VkImage image, VkImageLayout oldLayout, VkImageLayout newLayout)
{
VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer = beginSingleTimeCommands();

VkImageMemoryBarrier barrier = {};
barrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
barrier.oldLayout = oldLayout;
barrier.newLayout = newLayout;
barrier.srcQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
barrier.dstQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
barrier.image = image;
if (newLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL) {
    barrier.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_DEPTH_BIT;
}
else {
    barrier.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
}
barrier.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
barrier.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
barrier.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
barrier.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;
if (oldLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PREINITIALIZED && newLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL) {
    barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_HOST_WRITE_BIT;
    barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT;
}
else if (oldLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PREINITIALIZED && newLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL) {
    barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_HOST_WRITE_BIT;
    barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;
}
else if (oldLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL && newLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL) {
    barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;
    barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;
}
else if (oldLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED && newLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL) {
    barrier.srcAccessMask = 0;
    barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
}
else {
    throw std::invalid_argument("unsupported layout transition!");
}

vkCmdPipelineBarrier(commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT, 0, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &barrier);

endSingleTimeCommands(commandBuffer);
}
```

Comment: Any errors/warnings from the validation layers? Also is the fence unsignaled  at queue submission time?

Comment: I tried it with and without a fence instead of the vkQueueWaitIdle, but I removed it now, and it still doesn't work

Comment: What GPU (and driver) does this crash happen? And could you also add some more code, esp. the one inside the command buffer that you want to submit and everything related to queue transfer ownership of your buffers, images, etc. (looks like you use a dedicated transfer queue).

Comment: GPU is a GTX 860M, driver version 381.65, SDK version currently 1.0.49.0, and while debugging i just noticed that it only happens when transitioning image layouts, I will add the code for that now

Comment: What queue family index are the images owned by when you try to transition them. If you have a dedicatred transfer queue from a different queue family you may need to also add queue ownership transfer to your barriers by setting src/dstQueueFamilyIndex to the proper queue family indices instead of ignoring them and then also add a barrier to transfer ownership back to e.g. the graphics barrier.

Comment: @SaschaWillems the problem was that i didn't specify any owning queues at all when creating the images(i didn't even notice the field in VkImageCreateInfo), but for some reason it only breaks on my card(GTX 860M), not on a GTX 970M, post an answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the comments you need to keep track of image ownership, esp. if you work with different queue families.

So make sure you specify all queue familiy indices that access an image at creation time (`VkImageCreateInfo.pQueueFamilyIndices` and `VkImageCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndexCount`) if you're using `VK_SHARING_MODE_CONCURRENT`. If you don't need concurrent queue access to the images you can also go with `VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE` without the need to specify queue family indices.

When dealing with different queue family indices (graphics and compute e.g.) it's also important to do proper queue family ownership transfer in your barriers via their `srcQueueFamilyIndex` and `dstQueueFamilyIndex` members in both directions.